# Is it possible to display text from a CSS file?

Tags: css

I'm wondering it if is possible to display text on a HTML page from a CSS file.

For example for a web host instead of having 100MB display on a plan upon 4 pages and not having to edit each one but the CSS itself.

For example:

```
CSS
100MB
```

and than in text

Our plan has {text from css displays here}

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) pseudoselector. Suppose your "our plan has" part has an ID `planid`, and your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id = "planid">Our plan has</div>
```

Then you can do this in the CSS:

```
#planid:after {
    content: ' 100MB'; /*what the element will contain*/
    display: inline; /*it's inline*/
    /*more styling*/
}
```

The `:after` selector creates a pseudo-element **after** the selected element. To create one before it, use the `:before` selector.

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Va8dm/).

Answer (score 3):

Used to `after before` `properties`

yes do this as like this

**HTML**

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

**Css**

```
    div:after{
content:'100mb';
}
```

***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Ptec3wKa)***

***[more info](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html)***

Comment: What HTML tag do i use? Do i use <div id="ram"> i tried using that and it doesn't seem to display the content

Comment: you can chose any id or class as like this <div class="ram">Hello</div>  and css ram:after used   check to my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using pseudo elements like :after - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/LQy7T/

```
.your_class:after {
    content: "YOUR TEXT";
    color: red;
    background: blue;
    display: inline;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS is not designed to do that kind of work, it's for organizing styles and not for managing contents.
What you need is a variable to store your value and then show it many times. So you need PHP, JS, Ruby, Java or your favourite language.

Comment: The statement is mostly correct, but not an answer to the question; it should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: I would of use PHP however PHP is a little on the slow side and the idea is having a site fast as possible. Also the above answer works with CSS.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, it's not an answer to a question, but a solution to a problem. IMO it has much more educational value. (And don't let people use a microscope as a hammer.)

Comment: I think advising against bad practices and pointing in the good direction is the best we can do.